# Views + Search API not properly sorting by Commerce Price (seems random)

Tags: commerce, search

I have a search index View of product variations. The commerce_price field is indexed and exposed as sort option. However, when sorting by the price it appears mostly in order (Asc or Desc) but some items are not in the proper order (see screenshot)

I've tried indexing the price field as an integer, decimal, and string but it always has the same effect.

There are no additional sort items.
There are not any price adjustments or custom calculations.
There is no custom code affecting the Views or pricing.
I've tried wiping and rebuilding the index multiple times.
The View is using Better Exposed Filters.

Any ideas how I can get the products to sort by price correctly?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For testing something like this, I would add a view field to the display for the *Product variation datasource: Price > Number* to make sure it's the value I expect it to be. That should give you a good reference point to debug. Either A. the field **does not** have the value you expect or B. it does have the value you expect, but the sort is not working. Usually, I find that the field doesn't have the value I expect, e.g. A above.

Comment: Are these products being discounted, and that's why they appear out of order?

Comment: Nope. There are no discounts or any price alterations at all. Just the simple commerce price field with nothing extra going on.

Comment: I added price field output to a temporary View as suggested and this is leading me on the right path. See the new screenshot. Some (a lot but not all) of the "Price>>Number (indexed field)" values are empty but all of the "Product variation datasource" has the price. Any ideas on the discrepancy of the two fields?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Not sure exactly what is/was going on but the price sorting is now working. There was another identically named commerce price field in Views. Adding that field and removing the first one fixed the issue. I know, something unusual appears to be going on but at least the sorting is working now.